# Gitlab потребляет много ОЗУ

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab EE без активности почти 13 гб ОЗУ

Gitlab CI без активности почти 8 гб ОЗУ 150 процессов

Часть процессов от CI:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каждом из однотипных процессов можно наблюдать localhost:port

С чем это может быть связано? И как решить проблему с "отжиранием" ОЗУ?

Comment: Вставьте вывод в консоли в виде текста

Comment: Не процессов, а потоков. Отключите в настройках htop отображение потоков (`Hide userland process threads`), чтобы не вводить в заблуждение ни себя, ни нас

Comment: `Часть процессов от CI` – имхо, зря вы раннеры установили на тот же хост.

Comment: Имхо... всё было сделано по ману. А по факту - ресурсов достаточно, распределить нагрузку можно как угодно и куда угодно.